# Find the Eigenvectors of $\begin{pmatrix}1&-P\\P &-Q\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to find the eigenvectors of this matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}1&-P\\P &-Q\end{pmatrix}$

First I found the eigenvalues:

$det(A-\lambda_1)$

$det\begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda&-P\\p&-Q-\lambda\end{pmatrix}=(1-\lambda)(-Q-\lambda)+P^2=-Q-\lambda+Q\lambda+\lambda^2+P^2-Q$

$=\lambda^2+(Q-1)\lambda+P^2-Q$

$\implies \lambda_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{-(Q-1)\pm \sqrt{(Q-1)^2-4P^2+4Q}}{2}$

I know that I can find the eigenvectors by solving:

$(A-\lambda_k I)x=0$

but I am just getting wrong results. Wolfram Alpha says that the matrix has the following eigenvectors: [LINK](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors%20%7B%7B1%2C-P%7D%2C%7BP%2C-Q%7D%7D)

Could someone show me how I can calculate the eigenvectors?

Comment: You find eigenvectors by solving 
$$
(A - \lambda_k I)x = 0
$$
which may be what you meant, but isn't what you typed.

Comment: Yeah I meant that. I was being sloppy. Sorry.

Comment: As far as I can see, your eigenvalue solutions are now in accordance with the ones calculated by WolframAlpha. So we are one step closer. :-) You then end up with the two systems $(A-\lambda_1 I)x_1 = 0$ and $(A-\lambda_2 I) x_2 = 0$ for the eigenvectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ which can be solved by Gauss elimination. Because of the expression for the $\lambda$ being unwieldy this is more a challenge about making no mistake along the road than determining the solution $x_i$ for a homogenous linear system $(A - \lambda_i I) x_i = 0$.

Comment: @mvw Sorry for the late reply. I tried to solve it today and I always end up with the following equation $$\begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda_1 &-P \\P&-Q-\lambda_1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda_1&-P \\0&0\end{pmatrix} \\ \implies (1-\lambda_1)x_1=Px_2 \iff x_1=\frac{P}{1-\lambda_1}x_2 \implies \text{eigenvector:}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{P}{1-\lambda_1}\\1\end{pmatrix}$$ 

But if I plug in my eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ I get exactly the reciprocal of what wolfram alpha says $x_1$ should be. I don't know where I am making a mistake.

Comment: @ bluemoon, are $P$ and $Q$ matrices here? if yes, then can we calculate det$(A-\lambda I)$ in the way you did?

Comment: @rational. No they are real numbers as far as i know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\lambda \neq 1$ is an eigenvalue.  Then
$$
\pmatrix{1 - \lambda & -P\\ P & -Q - \lambda}
$$
is singular, so that the top and bottom rows are multiples.  Verify that the vector
$$
v = \pmatrix{P \\ 1 - \lambda}
$$
must be an eigenvector associated with $\lambda$.

Comment: I don't see how that is an eigenvector because: $$\begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda&-P\\P&-Q-\lambda\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} P \\1-(\lambda) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix} \\ \iff \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ P^2+\lambda^2+(Q-1)\lambda-Q \end{pmatrix}\not=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Why are you so sure that $P^2+\lambda^2+(Q-1)\lambda-Q \neq 0$? Remember, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.  **The top and bottom row are *multiples***.

Comment: I am sorry if this is elementary linear algebra but why is it important that the top and bottom row are multiples? Is $$P^2+\lambda^2+(Q-1)\lambda-Q$$

the characteristic polynomial? Is the polynomial always zero?

Comment: Write that the entries of the top row are $a$ and $b$.  Write that the entries of the eigenvector are $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Then we know that $ax_1 + bx_2 = 0$. Now, there is a $k$ such that the entries of the bottom row are $ka$ and $kb$.  We may then state that
$$
(ka)x_1 + (kb)x_2 = k(ax_1 + bx_2) = k0 = 0
$$
So, $(x_1,x_2)$ must be mapped to $(0,0)$.

Comment: And yes: the **definition of an eigenvalue** tells us that if you put $\lambda$ in to the characteristic polynomial, you should get $0$.

Comment: So are you saying the top and bottom row is linearly dependent?

Comment: That is usually implied by two things being multiples, yes

Comment: I am really sorry but I don't understand how that matrix has linearly dependent rows. I can see that this matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{pmatrix}$$
has linearly dependent rows but not $$\begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda &-P \\P&-Q-\lambda\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Any $2 \times 2$ matrix that is not invertible (i.e. has determinant $0$) has linearly dependent rows.  In fact, any matrix that is not invertible has linearly dependent rows.  If the rank of any matrix is $1$, then all of its rows are multiples.

Comment: I see. Let's just assume I recognize this matrix to have lin. dependent rows. How did you guess the eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix}P\\1-\lambda\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Solve $\pmatrix{1- \lambda & -P} \mathbf x = 0$

Comment: But to me that just raises the question how you came up with this system $$\begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda\\ -P\end{pmatrix} \vec{x}=\vec{0}$$. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: At this point, any explanation I give is going to repeat itself more than it already has.  I've said all I can say.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom, If $A$ is in block form, i.e. $P$ and $Q$ are matrices instead of being a number, can we say that the top and bottom row are multiples.?

Comment: @rational I very much doubt it

Answer (score 2):

I believe this part went wrong:
$$
-Q-\lambda+Q\lambda+\lambda^2+P^2 = \lambda^2+(Q-1) \lambda + P^2 - Q
\ne \lambda^2+(1-Q)\lambda+P^2 - Q
$$

Comment: Thanks. I edited my opening post. It was just a mistake while copying the question from my notes. I am still struggling to find the eigenvectors. Maybe you can give me a hint.

Comment: I edited my answer. It is still different.

Comment: I fixed the $Q-1$ part too.

Comment: So you got your problem solved?

Comment: No, not yet. I am still talking to Omnomnomnom in the comment section but there are several things I don't quite understand yet. I kind of have more questions than before. :D